# Android: Part of my extras are getting lost in pending intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-pendingintent, extras

I am making an Android app for the first time and I am having this problem.
When a user A sends a friend request to another user B, user B gets a notification. I wish when the user B click on the notification to be redirected to user A profile.

The main activity (Home in app) opens different fragments depending on from where the user is coming. A user profile is one such fragment.

This is how I am sending the notification from a presenter class for Main Activity.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("name" ,this.friendRequestFromUserName.toString());
extras.putString("email", this.friendRequestFromUserEmail);
extras.putString("notification", "notificationFriendRequest");

notificationIntent.putExtras(extras);

System.out.println("PUTTING EXTRA");
System.out.println(notificationIntent.getExtras().toString());
// output here is:
//Bundle[{name=The Lion King, email=mufasa@lionking.com, notification=notificationFriendRequest}]

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setContentTitle("New friend!")
    .setContentText(this.friendRequestFromUserName + " wants to be friends.")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    .setOngoing(false)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0));

builder.setOngoing(false);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

Notification not = builder.build();
not.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(123, not);
```

However in the main activity when user clicks on the notification only part of the Bundle is "arriving".
Here are the ways I tried to get the extras:

```
    extraName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    extraMail = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    extra = intent.getStringExtra("notification");
```

and

```
    System.out.println(intent.getExtras().toString());
    //Bundle[{notification=notificationFriendRequest}]
```

I also tried putting arrays as extra with the same result. Since part of my extra is arriving, but other is not, and I couldn't find similar topic and problem I decided to ask if somebody can help or explain why or how this can happen. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use unique `requestCode`s in `getActivity`?

Comment: No, I have not. Now that I tried generating random int for request code seems to not sending any extras at all.

Comment: Well I did, and when I am giving number different than 0 it is not sending any extras (I tried generating random number and also just putting other numbers than zero). I am also not sure what is the purpose of this code :/

Comment: so use the combination of unique `requestCode` and  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag

Comment: OH THANK YOU! That made it work!

Comment: and if you are using just one notification at given time (id = 123) you can skip different requestCodes,  just use 0 or whatever

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So as pskink suggested I added unique requestCode and PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag and that solved it.

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), Math.abs(generator.nextInt()), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Since I don't see how to mark a suggestion as an answer 'cause that is my first question here I am answering it myself. Thank you again, pskink!

Comment: and if you are using just one notification at given time (id = 123) you can skip different requestCodes, just use 0 or whatever

Comment: Android, never stops surprising me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting values in wrong way. As you are passing everything as a bundle in Intent , then first you have to get Bundle object first from intent like this

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`
and then get other strings from bundle object

Comment: When I am printing the extras like so
    System.out.println(intent.getExtras().toString());

this have the same result - the bundle only have one of three extras

Comment: instead of printing try debugging when you get extras. i don't think you're print line will print all extras in one go

Answer (score 1):

try to get fist the bundle object and then get the values like this, I hope this can help you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     try{
          Bundle data= this.getIntent().getExtras();
          extraName = data.getString("name");
          extraMail = data.getString("email");
          extra = data.getString("notification");
     }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the error can be in  notificationIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); because If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack. I will try to use notificationIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); instead

Comment: thank you, but this is also not the case (tried both flags together and separately). Note that the activity is actually launched, checks if there is extras is the intent, finds only one and opening the user fragment after that(if there is no extra the behaviour is different), only that user is left nameless and email-less.

Comment: And I also tried a bunch of other flags with no different result.